# mysql_grants.present fails to execute in salt-stack

Tags: salt-stack

I have the following state formula:

```
crm01.dbperms2:
  mysql_grant.present:
    - grant: all privileges
    - database: '*.*'
    - user: tester2
    - host: 10.1.0.2
```

When I execute the state.sls I get the following error:

```
   ID: crm01.dbperms2
    Function: mysql_grants.present
      Result: False
     Comment: Failed to execute: "GRANT all privileges ON *.* TO tester2@10.1.0.2" (MySQL Error 1045: Access denied for user 'debian-sys-maint'@'localhost' (using password: YES))
     Changes:
```

Nevertheless, if I add the grant manually, I get no error when executing the state.sls afterwards:

```
   ID: crm01.dbperms1
    Function: mysql_grants.present
      Result: True
     Comment: Grant all privileges on *.* to bup@10.1.0.2 is already present
     Changes:
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong.
Is there somebody who knows how to properly grant permissions to a user in mysql through salt-stack?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

I was having a similar issue and found that I needed to add the connection credentials - in this case I used my root login. I've also seen some instances where people specified the connection_host, but I didn't seem to need it.

```
crm01.dbperms2:
    mysql_grant.present:
        - grant: all privileges
        - database: '*.*'
        - user: tester2
        - host: 10.1.0.2
        - connection_user: root
        - connection_pass: {{pillar.root_db_password}}
```

Comment: Thank you. Adding connection_host did it for me!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but Here's how I have done it.

I have a added `.my.cnf` file with mysql user and password in it. This can be done for any user by putting the file in home directory.

```
/root/.my.cnf:
  file:
    - managed
    - source: salt://files/mysql/root-my.cnf
    - user: root
    - group: root
    - mode: 0600
    - template: jinja
```

Content of the file would look something like this.

```
[client]
  user=root # any user having grant permission
  password = {{ pillar['mysql']['server']['root_password'] }} # Password stored in pillar file.
```

Add the following line in mysql pillar file(any pillar file). This tells minion where to read required parameters for mysql connection from i.e un, pw, host, port etc.

```
mysql.default_file: /root/.my.cnf
```

Now you can use any of the mysql modules including `mysql_database, mysql_user, mysql.grant` which requires user permission.